# On The Temptations "For Lover's Only" Album, which songs feature which bass singer?

Tags: personnel

While recording The Temptations' album [*For Lover's Only*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Lovers_Only_(The_Temptations_album)), original bass singer fell ill and left the group; he passed away before the album's release. He was replaced in the group by former Parliament-Funkadelic singer Ray Davis, who appeared on the remaining tracks on the album.

I've been unable to find anywhere on which of the twelve tracks on the album Melvin Franklin appears, and on which Ray Davis appears. And because their voices are so similar (both crazy deep), I'm unable to tell which of the two of them is actually singing on the few songs where a bass singer has a featured spot.

So, my question is, which tracks on *For Lover's Only* feature Melvin Franklin and which feature Ray Davis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with *"which tracks on For Lover's Only feature Melvin Franklin"*, I found [this online version](https://books.google.se/books?id=gA0EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=ray%20davies%20for%20lovers%20only&source=bl&ots=4vNUN8c-23&sig=hppMiPCym9rGWi5pPAcqjTg2d6M&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjipLSqxOPJAhXnvHIKHQoRC0MQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q=ray%20davies%20for%20lovers%20only&f=false) of a billboard magazine:

> The album is created as a tribute to Melvin Franklin, the group's original bass, who passed away in 1995, and it contains his last recording with the group "Life Is But A Dream".

This can also be verified by the record on [Discogs](http://www.discogs.com/Temptations-For-Lovers-Only/release/5005278), which is a site for record collectors, but it also has a lot of information about album credits for the releases.

So I think it is safe to say that Melvin Franklin was only featured in that song, the rest seem to feature Ray Davis.

Comment: I'm not sure if this definitely means that it was the only song he was featured on, as the Wikipedia article I linked says "The album features the final recordings of Melvin Franklin" and "Franklin was replaced on the tracks he does not sing on". Note "recordings" and "tracks" being plural. That having been said, I can't find any other evidence to the contrary, so I'd say there's definitely a strong chance you're right. For now, +1, and if no other info comes up I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeKennedy I agree that it is not water proof. At least we have two sources that have the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Melvin was only able to do his interlude and
“Life Is But A Dream”.

Ray Davis did the rest of the songs.

Comment: This is good information, but do you have an authoritative source for it (liner notes, articles, etc.?) If not, there's no way for us to know if it's right or wrong. It also looks like it duplicates a post you posted several years ago (which was likely downvoted for the same reason--no source cited).

Answer (score -1):

Melvin was only able to do two tracks from the album.
“Some Enchanted Evening” and “Life Is But A Dream”.
Ray Davis was on the rest of the album.

Ray was on the following tracks:

“I’ve Grown Accustomed To Her Face”,

“At Last”,
 “Night And Day”,
“Time After Time”,
“What A Difference A Day Makes”,
“I’m Glad There Is You”,
“That’s Why I Love You So”, and 
“For Your Love/You Send Me”